# Remap key and get user input

Tags: vim

So I found out that doing

```
:%s//my new string/g
```

I can replace all occurences of my currently searced text

```
Hello, world! la la la Hello.
```

So if I step on Hello, press *, and then do :%s//Bye/g I can change all the Hello's to Bye's.

I just want to make a small remap to do that for me, I'm new to vim so this is super hard for me, I don't really know how to get the user input for a remap.

A reddit user suggested me

```
nnoremap <c-n> :%s///g<left><left>
```

So I can use  to trigger the replace, but it doesn't work, I guess because it doesn't specify the input anywhere? I'd like to do

```
<c-n> SOME NEW TEXT <enter>
```

and replace all Hellos with SOME NEW TEXT

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to write a small function to accept user input. e.g.:

```
function! ReplaceIt()
    call inputsave()
    let replacement = input('Enter replacement:')
    call inputrestore()
    execute '%s//'.replacement.'/g'
endfunction
```

you could put it in your vimrc. or another file and source it in vim.

then you can first search (by `/` or `*`, `#`...) then type:

```
:call ReplaceIt()
```

you will see the input prompt and you just give the replacement you want, and press `Enter`.

you could create a mapping for this function call, for example:

```
nnoremap <leader>r :call ReplaceIt()<cr>
```