# printing lines between mth and nth matched patterns

Tags: sed, grep, vim

I want to print all the lines between *mth* and *nth* matched pattern in a file. Lets say m is 10 and n is 90, In VIM I do a:

```
/pattern  
gg
100n
jdG
gg
10n
kdgg
```

How do i do this using sed or grep. I want the file to be manipulated without opening it in windows. I tried using vimscript with -c options but got some problems. Can we do this in vimscript without ever opening the file in window? I want to use this part (of truncating a file) as a part of shell script. I

Answer (score 2):

One easy way:

```
awk '/pattern/{ count++ } count > m && count < n' input
```

This will count pattern only once if it occurs multiple times on a line, but that can easily be fixed, and it is not clear what behavior you desire in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the question tagged with `vimscript` just add this answer. if it is not suitable here, please leave a comment, I would delete it.

your vim workflow could be simplified as: (for example `m=3,n=10`)

```
/pattern
3//,10//y x|%d|put x
```

- If you want it in vimscript, you can wrap it in a function:

  ```
  function! CutIt(m,n)
      execute a:m.'//,'.a:n.'//y x|%d|put x'
  endfunction
  ```

then you just  (after `/pattern`) `:call CutIt(3,10)`

- If you want to save the `/pattern` step:

  ```
  function! CutIt(p,m,n)
      execute a:m.'/'.a:p.'/,'.a:n.'/'.a:p.'/y x|%d|put x'
  endfunction
  ```

then you just call`:call CutIt('pattern',3,10)`

if you want to do it interactively. say, type a mapped key, then input `pattern, m, n` then `Enter` to let vim do the job for u. you can check this answer, how to accept user input in vim:
[Remap key and get user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273810/remap-key-and-get-user-input)

Comment: This is useful. However, I want to make those manipulation without opening the file, so can I make use of vim script from shell script?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '10,90!d' file.txt
```

prints lines 10 to 90 inclusive to STDOUT. To send the output to a new file use

```
sed '1,9!d' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: where is the pattern part? sed is not so easy to handle this, you need to play with hold space.